# Import contacts from MS exchange to Address Book

Tags: macos, exchange, import, address-book, apple-mail

Does anyone know how to import contacts from MS exchange to OSX Leopard Address book? I am able to get auto-complete in Mail for the email address stored in Exchange but I cannot import the contacts to Address book. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Entourage installed also, you can enable syncing with Entourage as the middle-man. Look in Preferences for the "sync services" pane and enable "Synchronize contacts with Address Book and .Mac".

Comment: That's a good idea. I will go try that out.

Comment: That works! But I wonder what will be the solution if I have no Entourage. Anyway at least for me that it solve. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As the previous poster says, use vCard. If you convert your Outlook Contacts to vCards, you can import them anywhere. Do it like this:

- Go to your Outlook contacts, and select them all (select one, press Ctrl-A).
  -Click Actions -> Forward as vCard.
- Depending on how many contacts you have, Outlook might be busy for a while. Eventually, you'll end up with a new e-mail message with all your precious contacts included as vCards.
- In the menu of the e-mail message, click File -> Save attachments. Select a folder, and save.
- Congratulations, you've just saved all your Outlook contacts as vCards, using only Outlook. You can discard the message, or send it to an e-mail account as a backup (I mailed mine to my Gmail account).

( I wrote these instructions on my blog a while back, but might as well post them here since they'll help more people. )

You can import vCards into Mac OS X Address Book, Gmail, and a whole lot of other programs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the lo-fi approach of copying (CTRL+A and copy) from an instance of Outlook into vcard files and importing them by hand?  Not strictly an import, but works for migrating...